# Problems with vertical centering and divs taking up space

Tags: css, html

I've got a few problems that I've been trying to remedy today.

I have an image 930 pixels high that I want to center in the exact middle of the screen. I used a recommended CSS snippet.

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 1280px;
height: 930px;
margin-top: -465px;
margin-left: -640px;
```

But unfortunately, if the viewport is smaller than 930px, it starts to crop the top of the area. I've tried a few methods, but nothing seems to help.

Also, in Chrome I've managed to get it so a number of sized, but moved divs don't require scrolling, however in Firefox and IE they seem to still take up space that they would before moving (using left: and top:)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say you want to centre in the "middle of the screen" do you mean the middle of the webpage within the browser? (Noting that the browser may not be maximised; I'm reading this page in a browser that is taking up only about a quarter of the screen.) Also, what do you mean by "moved divs"?

Comment: Also, regarding your comment about the top being cropped if the viewport is smaller than 930px (i.e., smaller than the img), what do you want to happen in that case? An image bigger than the window will have to either be cropped or resized to fit...

Comment: I've given up, and just accepted an 8px margin at the top. Looks alright. Anyway, the divs still take up space. I've got a number of divs that have specified heights. Now, I've moved them onto the image, to make clickable areas using the left and top commands. In Chrome, there is no scroll bar, as they all take up the correct space (on the image), annoyingly, in IE and Firefox they still seem to take up the original space before moving, meaning that there is a lot of spare space beneath my image. Is there anything that can be done about that? Thanks.

Comment: @smashman Do you have an example that we can take a look at? You can just place the image as a background to the main container and just overlay the divs in top.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/897064/SO/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a ugly solution but it works except for IE<8:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="positioner"></div><!--
    --><img src="yourimage" alt="" id="image" />
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
html,body,#positioner {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    text-align:center;
}
#positioner {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#image {
    max-height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as I wish. I put the image a background-image of my pageContainer div.

Comment: We still don't know what you wish ^^

Comment: In that case, I'll attempt to enlighten you.

Here's page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/897064/SO/index.html

You can see the css and html I've got there. It looks perfect in Chrome (other than the top cutting off), but annoyingly in IE and Firefox, it has major problems.